# Extracting the coordinates from a single contour detected by the findcontours in opencv using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here my code to store `(x,y)` in two found by `cv2.findcontours` in OpenCV python.

I have selected a random contour

```
c=contour[6]
```

Now I want x an y values detected in a separate array to perform some operation

numpy array are stored in this fashion.

```
[[[ 746  997]]
 [[ 744  998]]
 [[ 742  999]]
 [[ 740 1000]]]
```

I tried using this to extract x values

```
x = c[:,[0]]
```

but I'm getting the same array back.

So I try to extract using this loop

```
    for a in c:
      for b in a:
        s_x = np.append(s_x, b[0])
        s_y = np.append(s_y, b[1])
```

Is there a simple way to select x coordinates, than going through the loop and not having this error at all?

Comment: Use squeeze: `c.squeeze()[:, 0]` You have an extra dimension.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Can you write this in the answer? The solution did work. Might help someone person may be some other day

Comment: @COLDSPEED I tried to use `x= np.concatenate(x,selected_c)` but its same error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: Ah, does my answer not work?

Comment: Um, if it's an unrelated question, might want to open a new thread ;-)

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes but while appending it into a different array I'm getting this problem.

Comment: Check the shapes of `x` and `s_x`. I don't think you can use concatenate for your inputs. Try maybe `np.stack` with an axis?

Comment: @COLDSPEED opening another question for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your array has an extra dimension, so you could just remove it, and then indexing should work.

```
x = c.squeeze()[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cnt = cnts[1]             # choose one 
cnt = cnt.reshape(-1,2)   # change the shape 
xs  = cnt[:,0]            # get xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array has three dimensions. The details can be seen with the shape attribute.

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([[[ 746,  997]],
              [[ 744,  998]],
              [[ 742,  999]],
              [[ 740, 1000]]])
print(c.shape)
```

(4,1,2)

Once you have the shape, slice the array.

```
x = c[:,0,0]
print(x)
```

[746 744 742 740]